# Have to double submit when using Remote attribute based validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

We have a field on our model which has a [Remote] attribute.  When we store that field on a Hidden form element and then try to submit that form we have to click the submit button twice.  Also interesting is that the 2nd time we click it no remote validation is occurring (so says Fiddler).

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same problem, even if I make the hiddenfield visible by using TextBoxFor instead of HiddenFor.

Comment: Sadly no we did not.  I think we switched to manual Ajax validation for the field.

Comment: Did you also have knockout within your code at that moment? Because I think that has something to do with the problem on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to repro. If the hidden field is decorated with the Remote attribute you won't be able to submit the form no matter how many times you click on the submit button if the remote function sends `false`.

For example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Remote("Check", "Home")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Id = "1"
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Check(string Id)
    {
        return Json(Id == "2", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Because the remote function will always return false this form cannot be submitted. If the remote function returns true a single click would be enough to submit it assuming of course that the other validation passed.

Comment: We're actually using Html.HiddenFor as opposed to what you're doing there with the attribute.  I'll look at that.